Rate of convergence of Fourier modes of a mollifier on the torus in a negative regilarity Besov norm
Consider a standard mollifier  $\rho_\delta$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$ (the 2 dimensional torus) and let
$$
\hat{\rho_\delta}(m): = \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \rho_\delta(z) e^{2 \pi i m \cdot z} dz
$$
for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $|m|:=m_1+m_2$ and $\alpha \in (0,1]$. I'm trying to obtain an estimate for
$$
\| (1-\hat{\rho_\delta}(m)) |m|^\alpha \|_{\ell^\infty}
$$
Some similar results on mollifier let me think that $\| (1-\hat{\rho_\delta}(m)) m^\alpha \|_{\ell^\infty} \lesssim \delta^\alpha$.
I tried obtaining a bound at least for the case $\alpha=1$ , but even in that case I have
$$
\| (1-\hat{\rho_\delta}(m)) |m|\|_{\ell^\infty} \lesssim \left\| \int \delta(z)-\rho_{\delta}(z) dz \right\|_{L^1}
$$
Edit
As said in the answer below the estimate above oes not hold in general.
My goal is to obtain an estimate for
$$
\|u-u * \rho_{\delta} \|_{L^2}
$$
where $u$ is a distribution in the Besov space $B^{-\alpha}_{p,\infty}(\mathbb{T}^2$) equipped with the norm
$$
\|u\|_{B^{-\alpha}_{p,q}}:=\left\| \big(2^{-\alpha j} \|\Delta_j u\|_{L^p} \big)_{j \ge -1} \right\|_{\ell^q}
$$
where $\Delta_ju:= \sum_{\mathbb{Z}^2} \chi_j(m) \hat{u}(m)e^{2\pi im}$ is the (not-homogeneous) $j-th$ Littlewood-Paley block ($\chi_k:=\chi(\cdot/2^k)$ is a dyalic partition of unity, see here )
Similar result exists for Besov space with positive regularity, see e.g. this MathOverflow post.
My guess is that you have a similar estimate for the space with negative regularity,i.e.
$$
\|u-u * \rho_{\delta} \|_{L^2} \lesssim \delta^\alpha \|u\|_{B^{-\alpha}_{p,\infty}}
$$
I tried bounding the LittleWood-Paley blocks, but i ended up with an estimate that depends on
$$
|(1-\hat{\rho_\delta}(m)|^2
$$
Any idea how to obtain that bound?

I assume you have $\rho_1\in C_c^\infty((-\frac12,\frac12)^2)$ and then $\rho_\delta(x)=\delta^{-2}\rho_1(x/\delta)$ for $0<\delta<1$.
Clearly $\hat\rho_\delta(m)=\int_{\Bbb R^2}\rho_\delta(x)2^{2\pi imx}dx$. It is more convenient to work on $\Bbb R^2$.
The function $\hat\rho_1$ is Schwartz, therefore $\lim_{m\to\infty}\hat\rho_\delta(m)=0$. There is no hope to obtain such estimate unless you restrict to say $|M|\lesssim\delta^{-1}$.
For a bit of context, set $T_\delta f=\rho_\delta\ast f$, we have $T_\delta f\to f$ (say, in $L^p$ and for $f\in L^p$). The $T_\delta\to id$ is strong operator convergence but not uniform convergence.
There holds on the other hand $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\lesssim\delta^\alpha\|f\|_{W^{\alpha,p}}$ both on $\Bbb R^n$ or on $\Bbb T^n$. You need to incorporate the Sobolev norm of $f$ in the question first.
Update: Here $W^{\alpha,p}=B_{pp}^\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is not integer, it's called Sobolev–Slobodeckij space and is the special case to Besov space.
Alternatively you have $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{B_{pp}^{-\alpha}}\lesssim\delta^\alpha\|f\|_{L^p}$. The formula in your question is also incorrect.
In both case the "Fourier decay" follows from the different norms we impose on LHS and RHS: you lose $\alpha$-derivative in the estimate.
$\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{B_{pp}^{-\alpha}}\lesssim\delta^\alpha\|f\|_{L^p}$ and $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\lesssim\delta^\alpha\|f\|_{W^{\alpha,p}}$ both hold for $0<\alpha<1$.
Here is a sketch of $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\lesssim\delta\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$.
\begin{align*}
    \rho_\delta\ast f(x)-f(x)=&\int_{\Bbb R^n}\rho_\delta(y)(f(x-y)-f(x))dy=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\rho_\delta(y)\Big(\int_0^1\nabla f(x-ty)\cdot ydt\Big)
\\
    |\rho_\delta\ast f(x)- f(x)|\le&\int_{\Bbb R^n}|y\rho_\delta(y)\Big(|\int_0^1|\nabla f(x-ty)|dt\Big)dy
\\
    \|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\le&\int_{\Bbb R^n}|y\nabla\rho_\delta(y)|\Big(\int_0^1\|\nabla f(\cdot-ty)\|_{L^p}dt\Big)dy\le\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}\int_{\Bbb R^n}|y\rho_\delta(y)|dy
\end{align*}
The last one, by scaling we have $\|y\rho_\delta(y)\|_{L^1}=\delta\|y\rho_1(y)\|_{L^1]$, which gives $\delta^1$.
The case $0<\alpha<1$ follows from interpolating $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\lesssim\|f\|_{L^p}$ and $\|\rho_\delta\ast f-f\|_{L^p}\lesssim\delta\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}$. There is direct proof as well.
If you assume moment vanishing condition $\int x^\beta\rho_1(x)dx=0$ for all $0<|\beta|< M$, then the inequality hold for all $0<\alpha<M$ as well. The proof may not suits MSE here.

Thanks for the answer, I edited the question to add a bit more context. I already knew about the result for Sobolev spaces, I'm trying to extend it to the case of Besov norm with negative regularity (that is why i added the term $|m|^\alpha$ in the $l^\infty$ norm), but it is true, even in $B^\alpha_{p, \infty}$ the convergence of the convolution operator is not uniform

@Marco the Fourier coefficient is only bounded, but no decay at all. Besov is okay, I'll edit my answer later. It's essentially the same technique.

I completely agree that if $f\in W^{a,p}$
for $\alpha$
positive then the estimate holds. But I don't see how the same technique can be used when the space has negative regularity.

@Marco You need a good definition to start with. The simplest one I think is to use duality. The estimate for positive one can immediately implies that for negative space.

I would be interested in a more direct approach, as I'm actually working to the solution of non-linear SPDE-s, and using the duality argument does not generalize to the non-linear case

@Marco Again you need to show me what definition you are using for the Besov norm.

I added the definition I'm using. Basically I define the norm in terms of the littlewood-Paley blocks

I don't think you make it clear though. Do you want the left hand side to be $L^2$ while the right hand side is $L^p$-Besov? Again what you ask for cannot be true: either the left hand side is negative Besov space or the right hand side is positive Besov space.
